# WordPress meta box with custom upload loaction

Tags: wordpress, upload, location

I need a way to upload files to a custom location in stead of the upload folder from wordpress itself.
I googled somewhat but probably using the wrong words.
Can somebody give me a push in the right direction?

Note that I don't ask for the complete script to do this. 
I want to understand what I am doing rather than just copy and paste :-)

M.

Comment: You want the WordPress uploader to save files in a location that is not `/wp-content/uploads`? Or a completely different script to upload to a different location?

Comment: @doublesharp I want to build a meta box where I can upload page specific files to a custom location. So a location that extends `/wp-content/uploads` with a custom subfolder e.g. `/wp-content/uploads/my-custom-folder`

Comment: Then yes, you can write to any location that the web server process can write to. Since WordPress can write to `/wp-content/uploads` you can write to it as well, including creating subdirectories.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out. Now I need a way to do this. I have some "luck" in Google....

Answer (score 0):

You can write to any location that the web server process has write permissions. If you want to save an uploaded file to a different path under `/wp-content/uploads` you could use the [`wp_upload_dir()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir) function.

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']) && (!empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))){
    if ($_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { // no errors
        // get upload directory
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        // append the custom dir (and trailing slash!)
        $my_upload_dir = $upload_dir . "my-dir/";

        // get the filename of the upload (you might want to filter this)
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

        // move the file to your custom directory location and change permissions
        @move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $my_upload_dir . $filename );
        @chmod( $my_upload_dir . $filename, 0644 );
    }
}
```